# How to get values from Ruby class depending on another value

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I have a bit of code that formats an editing page depending on how many values a question has.

```
  <% (1..@question.qvalues_count.to_i).each do |qvalue| %>
    <% case qvalue
         when 1
          answer_value = @answer.value1
        when 2
          answer_value = @answer.value2
        when 3
          answer_value = @answer.value3
        when 4
          answer_value = @answer.value4
        when 5
          answer_value = @answer.value5
        end %>
       <label for="answer[value<%=qvalue%>]" class="fieldLabel" >Value<%=qvalue%></label>
      <input type="text" id="answer[value<%=qvalue%>]" name="answer[value<%=qvalue%>]" 
        value="<%=answer_value%>" 
      />
   <% end %>
```

That looks very messy and not extensible.  How can I replace the case statement with something that does not require me have a case for each value1..n class variable?

Comment: Any time you have a set of variables named `fooX` where `X` is a number, you have a code smell

Comment: They are fields from a database and can't be changed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have success with the old stand by, dynamic code, ie: the eval.

```
<% answer_value = eval( '@answer.value' + qvalue.to_s ) %>
```

or more correctly, as pointed out by Abe

```
<% answer_value = @answer.send( 'value'+qvalue.to_s) %>
```

for some reason unknown, this would not work.

```
<% answer_value = @answer.send( 'value#{qvalue}' ) %>
```

Comment: If you must go that route, you might want to consider using `send` as `eval` is dangerous. `@answer.send("value#{qvalue}")`

Comment: The reason it didn't work is you must use double quotes in order to allow [string interpolation](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Literals#Interpolation)

Comment: Another mystery of Ruby revealed.  I thought it was just like python, and did not matter which one you used.

Answer (score 1):

Put the answer values in a hash, then you can get the values with one statement. You could put this in a helper methods.

```
values = {1 => 'my value 1', 2 => 'my value'}
answer_value = values[qvalue]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a decent ORM (e.g. DataMapper) you should be able to specify what the database fields map to.  Otherwise a simple fix for your current situation could be something like this:

```
class Answer
  def value(i)
    self.send("value#{i}")
  end
end
```

Comment: I'm not using a decent ORM or at least I don't understand enough of what I'm doing yet.

Comment: Ah well not to worry you'll get there.  I'm not sure of your situation, but if you are dealing with an existing (legacy) database that you have to conform to and are going to use an ORM, I think DataMapper works best as it has some [nice features](http://datamapper.org/docs/legacy.html) for dealing with legacy schemas.  ActiveRecord works best when you're not constrained to an existing schema.  Might be worth looking into, depending on your situation.  Good luck